# How to access parent node from child

Tags: jsonata

How do I access a parent object from a child node. Seems that i can't access the scope

This is the source json

```
{
    "content" : {
        "date" : "2019-02-10T02:40:48Z",
        "production" : {
            "productionId" : "918",
        }   
    }
}
```

This is my Jsonata

```
{
  "productionType": "specificProducts",
  "products": [
    content.production.(
    {"usedProducts" : {
            "id" = productionId,
            "productDate" = content.date  // how do I access content
        }
    })
  ]
}
```

do I have to save "content" in some kind of variable and pass it to the child ?

Answer (score 2):

The Answer is `$$.content.date`

Here is the documentation of it

https://docs.jsonata.org/programming#built-in-variables

```
{
  "productionType": "specificProducts",
  "products": [
    content.production.(
    {"usedProducts" : {
            "id" = productionId,
            "productDate" = $$.content.date
        }
    })
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the % symbol to access the parent node from the context of a child node. You can use %.% to access the grandparent node, and so on.
You can read more about it in the documentation here: https://docs.jsonata.org/path-operators

This might be what you were trying to accomplish.  Since the query content.production returns an array, your query had to be adjusted slightly.

```html
{
  "productionType": "specificProducts",
  "products": [
    {
      "usedProducts": [
        content.production.{
            "id": $.productionId,
            "productDate": %.date
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to *not* dive down into the `production` element until you want to access its 'productionId' property -- like this:

```
{
    "productionType": "specificProducts",
    "products": [
        content.{
            "usedProducts": {
                 "id": production.productionId,
                 "productDate": date
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Then you can just access the 'date' property in the context of its parent `content` object.

Of course, these answers may or may not work as expected if the source object is more deeply nested, or contains arrays of child objects...

*But to answer your original question, "no" -- in JSONata, elements cannot know what "path" was used to dereference them.* Iirc, it was a concious design decision to ensure maximum flexibility and speed.